# Making "Search Everywhere" in PHPStorm similar to Sublime Text 3 "Goto Anything"

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, sublimetext3

I'm making the switch over from ST3 and I would like to replicate one of the search behaviours that I frequently used in ST3.

When I used Sublime Text 3, I would frequently press `Ctrl + P` to bring up the "Goto Anything" panel.

It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the ST3, uses fuzzy string matching to match any path and file name in your project.

So for example typing

`ze vi help` will match any file which contains that sequential list of characters in it's file path.

On the other hand, when you use PHPStorm for "Search Everywhere" it only searches the class name or the file name.

Is there a way to include this functionality? I would like PHPStorm to search the filepath and filename, rather than the PHP class names in the files.

Comment: I don't think it's possible -- here IDE makes different searches (by name/by class name/etc) and then just merges them into single results list where results from different search types are still displayed separately. I may only suggest to submit Feature Request ticket in their [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI)

Comment: Yep, I don't think it is possible either. I spent quite a while searching and many other people have had the same requests/concerns.

Answer (score 6):

If you miss a fuzzy file search like the one in Sublime, please vote for [IDEABKL-6959](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6959)

Comment: I was very disappointed to see the assigned developer's comment `why do you need this?` :/ But still I made the account just to vote for it, coz I need this functionality (I come from sublime)

Comment: It is finally implemented (in 2017.3 EAP), see https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/09/phpstorm-2017-3-eap-173-2290/

Answer (score 5):

You can use double shift, it is called "search everywhere"

What I did, I remapped double shift to cmd+p

Comment: Search Everywhere does not have fuzzy search logic. See the screenshot in the question for what's being highlighted and why.

Answer (score 1):

This feature will finally be available in version `2017.3`!

As of now you can only search the path while using `/` - so for example if you have a file in `app/http/controller/somecontroller.php` you can search it via `ttp/lle/con`.

BUT: The feature has been implemented in the new build, which is already available in an Early Access Programm

(see https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/09/phpstorm-2017-3-eap-173-2290/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the functionality in Sublime works exactly, but in PhpStorm you can use 3 ways of searching everywhere, as you can see [**here**](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/navigating-to-class-file-or-symbol-by-name.html).

1. `Cmd + O` will search by class name.
2. `Cmd + Shift + O` will search by file name.
3. `Cmd + Alt + O` will search by symbol (properties, methods, etc)

If you want to search for all files with `help` in their path, I am pretty sure you can do a file search with `Cmd + Shift + O` and then type `help/*`.

The keys are to include the forward slash `/`, otherwise it will search for files containing `help` somewhere in their filename.
And also use the wildcard `*`, otherwise it will search for folder names with those characters.

---

*Update*: you can also click `Shift` twice, and it will allow the same kind of search, but in files, classes, symbols and even PhpStorm tools - all at a time.